# How to force iOS notifications to show Notification Content App Extension on tap (bypassing swipe-down or 3D touch)?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, ios-app-extension

Is there a way to achieve this? Currently tapping the notification either opens the app or brings it to the foreground (if it's running in the background).

I feel like I'm spending a lot of time implementing a custom Notification Content App Extension view controller, only for users to never know about swiping down or 3D touching the notification alert to show these custom views.

Does anyone know if there's a way to just achieve the same effect as 3D touch or swipe-down with just the tap instead?

Thanks :)

Comment: You cannot achieve this, its the default behavior defined by iOS. Each and every app even created by them works the same. Since all the apps have the same structure the user of the iPhone should be used to this.

Comment: Hmmm...I was hoping that wasn't the case, but it makes sense. You should have posted this as an answer though, so I could mark it.